# Determine whether $(x_n)$ converges if $x_1= a , x_{n+1} = x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $x_1= a(>0) , x_{n+1} = x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Determine whether $(x_n)$ converges or diverges.

We have $x_1= a > 0, x_2= a+\dfrac{1}{a},  (\dfrac{1}{a} >0)$  which implies that $x_2 > x_1$

Then assume for induction: $x_k < x_{k+1} < a+1 $ (since $\dfrac{1}{x_k} < 1$)

$$x_k + \frac{1}{x_k} < x_{k+1}+ \frac{1}{x_{k+1}} < a + 1$$

$$\implies x_{k+1} < x_{k+2} < a + 1$$

This shows that that $x_k < x_{k+1} \Rightarrow  x_{k+1} < x_{k+2}$. Therefore $x_n < x_{n+1}$ for all $n \in  \mathbb N$.

It follows by the monotone convergence theorem that $x_n$ is increasing and bounded.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{1}{x_k}<1$? This is not right. Suppose $a=0.5$, then $\frac{1}{x_1}=2>1$

Comment: what should i put then? is my approach even close to what im supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $x_n^2 \geq  x_{n-1}^2 + 2 \Rightarrow x_n^2 \geq 2(n-1) \Rightarrow x_n \geq \sqrt{2(n-1)}$

Comment: sorry but i really dont see where you goin with this

Answer (score 1):

$(x_n)$ is monotonically increasing is clear. Let's prove that it is unbounded.
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}\\
x_{n+1}^2=\left(x_n+\frac{1}{x_n} \right) ^2\\
x_{n+1}^2=x_n^2+\frac{1}{x_n^2}+2\\
\geq x_n^2+2
\end{equation}
$\therefore x_n^2 \geq ...\geq a^2+2(n-1) \Rightarrow x_n\geq \sqrt{a^2+2(n-1)}$. It can be clearly seen that the right hand side of the equation is unbounded and hence the left hand side.